# Data Structure for steady stream of timestamped data

Tags: c++, data-structures, std

I have a steady stream of timestamped data, of which I want to always keep the last 5 seconds of data in a buffer. 
Furthermore, I would like to provide support for extracting data of a given subinterval of the 5 seconds, so something like

```
interval = buffer.extractData(startTime, endTime);
```

What std data structure would be most appropriate for this?

1) The fact that a new sample pushes an old sample out hints that a Queue would be a good data structure

2) The fact that we have to have random access to any elements, in order to obtain the sub interval maybe suggests that vector is appropriate.

Furthermore, what would be a good way to present the subinterval to the user?
My suggestion would be using two iterators?

Comment: Perhaps a slightly modified ring-buffer (which is often implemented with a vector-like data structure on the back end)?

Comment: If you want to keep *5 seconds* of timestamped data, you cannot rely on new data pushing old data out, unless you have synthetic timestamps.

Comment: @gha.st Thank you for your comment, I am aware of that, I what I meant is that pushing out old data will be a frequent operation.

Comment: @ twalberg Thank you. 

Sine the data does not come in at a constant frequency the size of the buffer will vary.

Comment: A [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) or [double ended queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) would be appropriate. The difficulty is in locating start time and end time. Since timestamps are (presumably) monotonic, you can use a binary search to find start time and end time in log n steps. Is that fast enough?

Comment: @user695652 That might be something worth posting in the question - your current wording of "a steady stream of timestamped data" seems to suggest (at least to me) a regular sampling frequency, and you don't state anything else in the question that would make me think the data arrival is sporadic in nature...

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are in a fairly performance critical part of the code, a [`deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) would seem reasonable. It can grow and shrink to accommodate changes in your data rate and has reasonable performance for double-ended queue operations and random access.

If the code is performance sensitive (or, even worse, has real-time requirements on top, as is the case with many timestamped buffers), you need to prevent memory allocations as much as possible. You would do this by using a ring buffer with a preallocated array (be it through [`unique_ptr<T[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at) or [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) and either dropping elements when the buffer size is exceeded, or (taking one for the team and) increasing its size.

By never reducing size again, your ring buffer might waste some memory, but remember that in most cases memory is fairly plentiful.

Representing intervals by two iterators or a range object is both common, and although the C++ standard library often prefers iterators, my personal preference is for range objects due to their (in my opinion) slightly better usability.